# How to connect two dimmers to control two sets of lights independently

Tags: electrical, lighting, dimmer-switch

I have just moved to Germany, and have a room with a double-gang system. The lower is a rotary dimmer which controls the lights in the kitchen, and the upper is a double rocker switch that simply turns living-room lights on or off.

I want to replace the double-rocker switch with another dimmer. I bought the same type of Busch dimmer as the one that controls the kitchen lights and tried to fit it. The problem is that I now have the new rotary dimmer fitted, but when you turn it on, it switches both kitchen and living-room lights on. Moreover, it is dimming the living-room. The other dimmer for the kitchen does not dim, it only switches the light on or off.

So I have two dimmers: one works as an on/off switch for both dimmers (I don't want this, I want them to be independent) and dims itself, but other dimmer will not switch on/off independently and does not dim!

The existing wiring was 1 black wire and 2 yellow wires coming into the top double-rocker, and 1 black wire coming into rotary dimmer. Between both dimmer and rocker was a single brown traveler wire crossing between. I have tried simply to replicate the wiring but to no avail.

Front view of Busch Dimmers

[image]

Wiring of both Dimmers

[image]

Rear view of original Rocker switch wiring, top far right had brown wire, next to Black wire

[image]

Front view Rocker

[image]

Complete Double Gang Dimmer Below for Kitchen, and Rocker above for Living Room

[image]

Notes on photos:

1. Front view of Busch Dimmers: Original wiring was as the photo shows, except that the rocker switch  on the left (now the new dimmer) had both yellow wires going to it (see photo). I changed this as dimmer were not dimming, and placed wire across to second dimmer, which briefly made both dimmers work.
2. Front Overhead view of Dimmers:  the orange wire in photos is in fact the Black wire (extended).
3. The rear-view of the original Rocker switch (to Kitchen, no. 5 on block) had Brown wire going to Top Far Right (right of the ‘L’ ) next to which was the Black wire. I hope this explains things a bit better.

Also forgot to mention: 
The kitchen lights are 4 x 30 watts
The living room lights are   4 x 60 watts

Comment: Please use the [edit] link just underneath your question to update it. Thanks!

Comment: I would be very grateful if someone, anyone would answer my question. Many Thanks, Max

Comment: I see this is languishing... I'm happy to try and work it out with you, but I have two questions. One, you mentioned both dimmers briefly worked. As in, exactly correctly? And now they malfunction as you described? Also, what's your comfort level with electrical work? It certainly sounds like a wiring error which may require some diagnosing. Let me know and I'll be glad to try and talk you through it.